# NGINX adds a domain name in URI - leads to 404 Not Found

Tags: nginx

Login URL - https://domain1.com
Initial URL after login - https://domain1.com/test
Clicking another page - https://domain1.com/newpage
Clicking back Initial Page - https://domain1.com/domain1.com/test - this fails

I am just doing a proxy_pass to the upstream server based on IP and port for root location /. Everything works apart from the above issue. tried checking the specific URI(/domain1.com/test) to rewrite to https://domain1.com/test for location - but doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

within the location block for URI "/domain1.com/test" - we trimmed the domain name and used the redirect option. This works now.